# Pandas categorical variable with missing data

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

Suppose that I have this dataframe:

```
dfdic = {"col1": ['azul', 'amarillo', 'amarillo', np.nan], "col2": [4, 5, 8, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dfdic)
```

I want to convert the `col1` field to dummy variables. I can do that by:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['col1']).head()
```

which gives

```
    col2    col1_amarillo   col1_azul
0   4.0     0               1
1   5.0     1               0
2   8.0     1               0
3   10      0               0
```

The NaN in `col1` has been replaced by two zeroes in the dummy variables. This makes sense because it is saying that the instance does not belong to any of the categories. However, how can I replace those zeroes by NaNs, so I could have

```
    col2    col1_amarillo   col1_azul
0   4.0     0               1
1   5.0     1               0
2   8.0     1               0
3   10      NaN             NaN
```

Comment: If `df2` is your df with dummies, `df2[df2["col2"].isna()] = np.nan`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) + [`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html)

You can use `mask` to make selected columns null dependent on another series.

```
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].mask(df['col2'].isnull())

print(df)

   col2  col1_amarillo  col1_azul
0   4.0            0.0        1.0
1   5.0            1.0        0.0
2   8.0            1.0        0.0
3   NaN            NaN        NaN
```